# Generar código a un articulo al dar click en un botón especifico

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2014

Solicito de su amable ayuda.
tengo una tabla articulo y cuneta con 2 tipos de código.
el primero es su idarticulo y el segundo es el código con el que se va a buscar en el registro (SKU).

quiero que al momento de ingresar un articulo y al presionar el botón "Generar código", este me genere un código aleatorio pero que a su vez no se repita en el registro..

ejemplo

idarticulo: 1001

SKU: 5030176.

eh podido generar el codigo aleatorio pero no le encuentro como hacer que no me genere el mismo al hacer otro registro.

gracias de antemano..

Acá esta mi codigo que tengo para que me genere el SKU

```
 //evento generar codigo SKU
    private void BtnGenerarCod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int a = rnd.Next(1000, 9000);

        this.txtSku.Text = "503" + a.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Hola, edita por favor la pregunta e indica el código que has realizado.

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo de como generas ese codigo aleatorio? entiendo el id es un valor secuencia, entonces la aleatoriedad solo la necesitas en el sku, no?

Comment: ¿Es necesario que el código tenga ese formato? Si no es así, puedes utilizar: var sku = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); que te genera strings con el siguiente formato: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: muchas gracias por responder. ya e editado la pregunta y puse el código que implemente para generar el SKU

Comment: puedes obtener el Dia, Hora, Minuto y Segundo y concatenarlo al por ejemplo "503"+"1375612" asi tendras la seguridad que siempre sera unico

Comment: Estas usando una base de datos? porque podrias validarlo en esta mediante una consulta

Comment: Se como hacer una consulta en el sql.. pero como podría este ayudarme a que el SKU no se repita .. porque una vez finalizado el programa ya no podré estar consultando la BD..

Comment: "finalizado el programa" ? la validacion se realiza cuando generas el sku, ademas aunque cierres la aplicacion los datos en la db persisten

Comment: Oh.. ya entiendo, no había captado bien la idea.. gracias por el tips. 

Comment: si le pones a tu Primary Key de la base de datos que sea autoincremental, siempre sera unico y numero como deseas en el SKU.